# how to avoid the number row appearing from android keyboard?

Tags: android

In my project , I use an editext for entering names and I require only a keyboard without number rows on the top. I would like to avoid the appearance of the number 
row on top line of the keyboard. How to do it?

Comment: Try setting `android:inputType="text"` to the `EditText`.

Answer (score 3):

The decision as to whether or not to show a row of numbers on a soft keyboard is up to the implementer of the soft keyboard, not you. Some soft keyboards will always have it. Some will never have it.

The `android:inputType` attribute is where you provide a hint of what you want, that some soft keyboards may elect to honor. However, there is no `inputType` option for "all possible characters except numeric digits" or even "only letters". And, more generally, there is no option for you to say "well, I want the user to be able to enter digits, but please do not put those digits on the main keyboard, but instead have the user switch to some alternate layout to get those digits".